# Assigning a class variable and then reassigning in a definition without using global in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my question is in the title and the following two snippets of code are my attempts around this.  I am trying to assign a variable as soon as the script is started and then just run the loop definition at certain time intervals and update that same variable.  I do not want to use a global.

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

class DudeWheresMyCar(object):
    counter = 20
    stringInit = 'initialized string'

    def loop():
        stringNew = 'this will be updated with a changing string'
        if (stringInit == stringNew):      #Error line
            print(stringNew)
        elif (stringInit != stringNew ):
            stringInit = stringNew
        pass

    task.LoopingCall(loop).start(counter)
    reactor.run()
```

This leads to an error undefined stringInit.  I know why I am getting this error so I made an attempt to fix this using the .self variable and the code is below.

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

class DudeWheresMyCar(object):
    counter = 20

    def __init__(self):
        self.stringInit = 'Initialized string'

    def loop(self):
        stringNew = 'this will be updated with a changing string'
        if (self.stringInit == stringNew):
            print(stringNew)
        elif (self.stringInit != stringNew ):
            self.stringInit = stringNew
        pass

    task.LoopingCall(self.loop).start(counter)    #Error line
    reactor.run()
```

I get an error that says that self is undefined.  I understand what is causing both scenario's to throw errors but I am not sure how to change my approach to accomplish my goal.  I also ran into using a singleton but that still does not fix the problem in scenario 2.

Comment: Is that really the indentation you want on the `task.LoopingCall` line?

Comment: @FamousJameous yes that is the correct indentation.  It is outside of the definition which is why I am running into an issue but that is how the timed loop works.  If I put it inside of the definition, the timer no longer works correctly.  I need this timer because the loop needs to be strictly executed and this method does not have any time float issues.

Comment: You've never created an object with the `DudeWheresMyCar` class. What is `self` supposed to refer to?

Comment: @Barmar Removing the entire class structure or removing object still does not fix either issues in the two snippets of code. I wanted self to refer to the entire class structure like I thought a lot of programs I've seen do but I am still new to the language.

Comment: That's not how `self` works. It refers to a specific class instance. You do `d = DudeWheresMyCar()` and then `d.loop()`, and then `self` refers to `d`.

Comment: @Barmar I believe I just worded my reply incorrectly but yes I would like self to refer to DudeWheresMyCar().  I think we may be getting a bit off topic though as I don't think this is helping me towards a solution.  If I am taking the wrong approach then please help me take the right one using an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `classmethod`, and you need to start the the task outside of the class definition. I would expect something like the following code to work

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

class DudeWheresMyCar(object):
    counter = 20

    stringInit = 'Initialized string'

    @classmethod
    def loop(cls):
        stringNew = 'this will be updated with a changing string'
        if (cls.stringInit == stringNew):
            print(stringNew)
        elif (cls.stringInit != stringNew ):
            cls.stringInit = stringNew


task.LoopingCall(DudeWheresMyCar.loop).start(DudeWheresMyCar.counter)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: thank you so much!  This not only worked beautifully but classes, definitions and how to reference them is starting to make a lot more sense.